# How do I specify the screen-name for a command (Gnu-Screen)?

Tags: shell, gnu-screen

If there are 2 gnu-screens, with the name: screen1 and screen10.
If we want to do something with screen1, I can't, because if I try as example to print something to the screen, it will say that there is a Screen screen1 and screen10. so I need to specify my command so it will print it to screen1 without any problems, but how can specify it, so this command below will work?

```
screen -x screen1 -p 0 -X stuff `printf "test\r"`
```

Manual screen:
http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html (I couldn't find the argument that would solve this problem)

Answer (score 0):

Try `-S {session_name} -X {commands}`.

example:

```
screen -S screen1 -X stuff `printf "test\r"
```